# xna model repeat

Tags: model, xna, repeat

I'm wondering is there anyway of repeating the ground model infinite times in XNA. For example in this sample http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/chasecamera ?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no. If you try to draw an infinite number of polygons not only will your memory run out and your program crash, but the hardware would take an infinite amount of time to render the scene.

To get around this, game developers use tricks like skyboxes and unreachable terrain to make the player think the world is infinite. So if you want a finite world with a repeating ground texture, just draw the ground texture a bunch of times in a grid and put a skybox that covers the outer edges of the ground.

If you REALLY want an infinite looking world, you can do a trick where the skybox and ground move with you. So just set the velocities of the ground and the skybox to be the velocity of the sprite that is moving.

Answer (score 0):

Like that ! It's my custom sample. You can repeat a model from a matrix index with different texture

```
//Draw a ground land
    private void draw_groundLand1(int[,,] MatriceWorldCube,Vector3 position_model_origin)
    {

        int hauteur = MatriceWorldCube.GetLength(0);
        int largeur = MatriceWorldCube.GetLength(1);
        int longueur = MatriceWorldCube.GetLength(2);

        Vector3 pos_reference = position_model_origin;

        for (int epaisseur = 0; epaisseur < hauteur; epaisseur++)
        {

            for (int collone = 0; collone < largeur; collone++)
            {

                for (int ligne = 0; ligne < longueur ; ligne++)
                {

                    //Vérifie si l'index de la matrice comporte bien un matériaux a placer
                    if (MatriceWorldCube[epaisseur, collone, ligne] != 0)
                    {
                        // Copy any parent transforms.
                        Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[model_ground_land1.Bones.Count];
                        model_ground_land1.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

                        // Draw the model. A model can have multiple meshes, so loop.
                        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model_ground_land1.Meshes)
                        {
                            // This is where the mesh orientation is set, as well 
                            // as our camera and projection.
                            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
                            {
                                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                                effect.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index]  *
                            Matrix.CreateRotationY(cubeGroundLand1_modelRotation) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(position_model_origin);
                                effect.View = View;
                                effect.Projection = Projection;

                                //Applique la texture en fonction du type de matière définit dans l'indice de la matrice
                                switch (MatriceWorldCube[epaisseur, collone, ligne])
                                {
                                    case 1:
                                        effect.Texture = text_ground_land1;
                                        break;

                                    case 2:
                                        effect.Texture = text_ground_land2;
                                        break;

                                    default:
                                        break;
                                }
                            }

                            // Draw the mesh, using the effects set above.
                            mesh.Draw();
                        }

                    }

                    position_model_origin.X = (float)(ligne+1);
                }
                position_model_origin.X = pos_reference.X;
                position_model_origin.Z = (float)(collone+1);

            }
            position_model_origin.Z = pos_reference.Z;
            position_model_origin.Y = (float)(epaisseur+1);

        }
        position_model_origin.Y = pos_reference.Y;
        position_model_origin = pos_reference;
    }
```